# How to use QCursor::pos() without using QApplication?

Tags: c++, c, qt, qt-creator, qapplication

I'm writing a project in Qt Creator, and if I write

```
QPoint cursorPos=QCursor::pos();
```

then cursorPos={-2147483648,-2147483648} which is obviously wrong. However, if I write

```
QApplication *application=new QApplication(argc,argv);
QPoint cursorPos=QCursor::pos();
```

then cursorPos is the correct mouse position. Is there any way I can get QCursor::pos() to work without QApplication? Thanks. :D

Answer (score 4):

`QApplication` object does so much initialization. One of the `QApplication`'s main areas of responsibility in the Qt documentation :

> It manages the application's mouse cursor handling, see setOverrideCursor()

Also from the Qt documentation about `QCursor` :

> Note: It is possible to create a QCursor before QGuiApplication, but
>   it is not useful except as a place-holder for a real QCursor created
>   after QGuiApplication. Attempting to use a QCursor that was created
>   before QGuiApplication will result in a crash.

So it seems that it is not possible to use `QCursor` without `QApplication` or `QGuiApplication`.